# Javascript Download file link is closing popup window before download popup

Tags: javascript, popup

I'm creating a simple feature where I need to create a download file link which gives a popup window to download and as soon as user saves or cancel the download, the window should close. This is the JS code I used.

```
function download(filename, text) {
  var element = document.createElement('a');
  element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
  element.setAttribute('download', filename);

  element.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(element);

  element.click();

  document.body.removeChild(element);
  window.close();
}
```

If I remove the window.close() statement, it works smooth but with window.close(), the new window closes before it could throw a popup window for download.
Can anybody here please help?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this eventually adding the HTML block

```
<body onload="closeWindow()"></body>
<script>
function closeWindow() {
    self.close();
}
</script>
```